# Бот на Discord.js вылетает после отправки сообщения об удалении/редактировании сообщения

Tags: javascript, discord-api

Делаю бота на систему аудита. Должен при удалении/редактировании сообщения, отправлять информацию о нем(где удалено, старое и новое содержание и тд.). Сообщение отправляет, но потом сразу вылетает, прошу помочь. Блок try/catch исключения не обрабатывает.

Вот сам код:

```js
try{
    client.on("messageDelete", function(message){
        let deleteEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed();
        deleteEmbed.setColor([255,50,50]);
        deleteEmbed.setTitle("Сообщение было удалено");
        deleteEmbed.addField("Сообщение: ", message.content);
        deleteEmbed.addField("Автор: ", message.author, true);
        deleteEmbed.addField("Канал: ", message.channel, true);
        deleteEmbed.setFooter(`ID сообщения: ${message.id}; ID автора: ${message.author.id}`);
        message.guild.channels.find("id", config.auditLogChannel).send(deleteEmbed);
    });
    client.on("messageUpdate", function(oldMessage, newMessage){
        let editEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed();
        editEmbed.setColor([255,255,50]);
        editEmbed.setTitle("Сообщение было отредактировано");
        editEmbed.addField("Старое сообщение: ", oldMessage.content);
        editEmbed.addField("Новое сообщение: ", newMessage.content);
        editEmbed.addField("Автор: ", newMessage.author, true);
        editEmbed.addField("Канал: ", newMessage.channel, true);
        editEmbed.setFooter(`ID сообщения: ${newMessage.id}; ID автора: ${newMessage.author.id}`);
        newMessage.guild.channels.find("id", config.auditLogChannel).send(editEmbed);
    });
}catch(e){

}
```

Ошибка:

````
C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\RichEmbed.js:166
    if (!/\S/.test(value)) throw new RangeError('RichEmbed field values may not be empty.');
                           ^

RangeError: RichEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at RichEmbed.addField (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\RichEmbed.js:166:34)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\bot.js:313:19)
    at Client.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at MessageUpdateAction.handle (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageUpdate.js:13:16)
    at MessageUpdateHandler.handle (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageUpdate.js:7:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Programming\js\EliteBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Зачем пользоваться этим через `function`?

Код только `message delete`, а остальное потом можно самому переделать:

```
 client.on('messageDelete', async message => {
     const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
         .setAuthor('Сообщение удалено', message.guild.iconURL)
         .addField('Отправитель', message.author.tag, true)
         .addField('Канал', message.channel, true)
        .addField('Содержание', message.content)
         .setColor("RANDOM")
         .setTimestamp()
       .setFooter(`Сервер: ${message.guild.name} | Овнер сервера: ${message.guild.owner.user.tag } `, message.guild.iconURL);
    await guild.channels.find("id", config.auditLogChannel).send(embed);
  })
~~~
```